# How to get django model object in save method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to override `save` method in django.

I am using Django REST framework so basically serializer handles all saving of model.

```
def save(self, split=True, **kwargs):
    if split:
        result = super(Entry,self).save(**kwargs)
        logger.warn(result)
        logger.error(self)
        #tasks.split_entry(self)
    else:
        super(Entry,self).save(**kwargs)
```

Now I want to pass the object being saved to my tasks but I am not sure if self is object or result is object.

I don't want to interrupt the process because I think django rest needs to get that saved object to return to request. So I am confused how to use `super` here.

If I do the above process I can't see any logging. I think it skips them.

Comment: Have you check the value for 'result' ?

Comment: try post_save signal handler

Comment: `Entry` object is in `self`, if you want keep the log and execute the save normally (and you don't want to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/)), try to execute `super` method at the end.

Comment: @Gocht . if i want to execute some stuff after object is created by save  then do i have to use  super before and then do my stuff

Comment: No problem, you're not modifying the object, so I think you can do the `super` just where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `self`. Django models' `save` method does not return a value so your `result` variable is `None`.

Comment: I have a very similar situation but I don't quite get where to put `self`
Can you please give an example?